# Environment map affects scene lighting after update to r131

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a general scene where I'd like to show different kind of models. Depending on the source of the model sometimes the model contains `MeshPhongMaterial`, sometimes `MeshStandardMaterial`, and sometimes both of them.

I also have a specific lighting model with an `AmbientLight`, and a `DirectionalLight` that points always to the same direction as the camera, so you will see clearly what you are looking at right now.

To make `MeshStandardMaterial` look better I've also added an environment map to the scene (not the materials), and I was pretty satisfied with the result.

Here is the result with r130 (Phong material on the left, Standard material on the right):
[image]

After I update three.js to r131 the result looks something like this:

[image]

I understand that environment maps are auto-converted to PMREM from r131, and this causes the change. I also understand that this is more correct than using non PMREM environment maps, but now it messes up my scene.

On some other topic it was recommended to remove ambient and directional light (because lighting now comes from the environment), but it results in this:

[image]

Now the object with standard material looks fine, but the object with phong material is completely black. I've also lost my previous feature that the directional light always points where the camera looks.

By removing ambient light only I get this (still not what I want to achieve):

[image]

So basically my question is: Although I know that this is not physically correct, is there a way to apply an environment map that doesn't affect the lighting of the scene, but affects reflections of standard materials?

Here you can find the code of the mentioned scene:
https://github.com/kovacsv/Online3DViewer/blob/dev/sandbox/three_envmap_issue/three_viewer.html

And here you can see it live:
https://raw.githack.com/kovacsv/Online3DViewer/dev/sandbox/three_envmap_issue/envmap_issue.html

Comment: Any way you could share the code where you create the materials? Maybe it's one of the properties, like [envMapIntensity](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=standard#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMapIntensity) or something like that. I'm looking at the [changelog between r130 -> r131](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r131) and I don't see anything noteworthy that would apply to your StandardMaterial.

Comment: Good point, I've edited the question with a link to the code.

Comment: @kovacsv You said "it was recommended to remove ambient _and_ directional light". No, removing only ambient light would be reasonable -- and only if you are using `MeshStandardMaterial` or `MeshPhysicalMaterial`. Also see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/22178#issuecomment-887950445.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically my question is: Although I know that this is not physically correct, is there a way to apply an environment map that doesn't affect the lighting of the scene, but affects reflections of standard materials?

No, there isn't. `MeshStandardMaterial` and `MeshPhysicalMaterial` require now a more strict PBR workflow. As you pointed out correctly, your previous setup was physically incorrect. This has been fixed and there are no plans right now to allow previous workflows again. Environment maps are considered to be used as IBLs. So conceptually they always affect the lighting no matter how you parameterize the material.

The solution for your use case is to a) use phong materials or b) update the lighting of your scene and accept the new style.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I was afraid of. Do I understand correctly that with the new setup there is no way to have a scene with both phong and standard materials where all material display is acceptable?

Comment: @kovacsv For `MeshPhongMaterial`, environment maps only provide specular reflections -- you have to provide ambient light separately. For `MeshStandardMaterial` and `MeshPhysicalMaterial`, ambient light is inferred from the environment map.

Comment: So if I use a `MeshPhongMaterial` and a `MeshStandardMaterial` in the same scene together with an environment map, I have two options: 1) Provide ambient light that will mess up my standard material - it will be too bright. 2) Do not provide ambient light that will mess up my phong material - it will be very dark. So if I understand correctly I have to choose between the material types, and there is no way to mix them.

Comment: @kovacsv `MeshStandardMaterial` is a PBR material; `MeshPhongMaterial` is not. You can use them both in the same scene, but do not expect them to render the same.

Comment: I don't want them to render the same, but render with a color that somewhat near their base color. Now it seems that is not possible after r131, so probably I have to find another solution.